# making jquery flip animation responsive--- not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to use flip card animation (https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/) responsive, but it's not working... the back side width of the card is 100%. If I force it to 33.333%, the row gets messed up.

Please help me out!

```js
$(function(){
    $("#card").flip({
        trigger: 'hover'
    });
});
```

```css
.albumbox img {
 height: 450px;
 object-fit: cover;
}

.albumbox {
 height: 450px;
}


#card {
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 450px;
 width: auto;
}

#card .back {
    background: #2184cd;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/v1.0.20/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>

<main>
    <div class="row">
     <h2>Singles <i class="material-icons">album</i></h2>
        <div id="card">
            <div class="albumbox col-4 front">
                <img src="http://theblueliar.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Jessie-J-012.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="albumbox4_detail back">
            detail back
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="albumbox albumbox5 col-4">
          <img src="http://theblueliar.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Jessie-J-012.jpg">
         </div>
            <div class="albumbox albumbox6 col-4">
             <img src="http://theblueliar.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Jessie-J-012.jpg">
         </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
.albumbox img{
    height: 450px;
    object-fit: cover;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Since the image original size is bigger than the container width. Ur getting a scroll. Setting max-width to the img tag ensures it doesnt exceeds parent width(Responsive)